# Firebase real-time database substring query

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, substring, filtering, keyword

I am going to look up with keyword substring "vi" for key "full_name".  How can I do that?

```
[{
    "full_Name": "David Beckham",
    "email": "davidbeckham@gmail.com"} ,
 {
    "full_Name": "Cristiano Ronaldo",
    "email": "critinanoronaldo@gmail.com"
}]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to order and query based on a certain key

```
dbQuery.orderByKey().startAt(SUBSTRING).endAt(SUBSTRING+"\uf8ff");
```

For more info you can look at the official documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries

Answer (score 0):

Query firebase key with a substring is possible

```
let node = await db.ref('yourPath').orderByChild('full_Name').startAt('!').endAt('SUBSTRING\uf8ff').once('value');
```